# Keyboard is hiding on scrolling

Tags: android, android-edittext, textinputlayout

In my xml, I am having TextInputLayout edittext inside NestedRecyclerView, when focus is on first edittext and I am going to focus on second edittext then keyboard is hiding and showing, on scrolling also keyboard is hiding but focus is still there.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Post your code so that reader can understand correctly.

Answer (score 0):

implement OnTouchListener in your project code

```
MyRecycleView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);

        return false;
    }
});
```

This might help you [Implementation of RecyclerView that will dismiss keyboard](https://gist.github.com/gnumilanix/da4bb5385aebcc51b35b597de8e482b7)

Comment: I am not using Recyclerview, only Nestedscrollview, keyboard should not hide when I am clicking on next edittext or scrolling but it is hiding and then coming again.